# Scope of a css class applied to a div?

Tags: css, html, styling

I would like to apply some special styling to a section of a page on my website.

I thought that by defining something like this:

```
h2.privacy_policy {
    color: #456123;
    padding: 10px 20px 30px 40px;
    margin: 40px 30px 20px 10px;
}
```

and by applying the class to a wrapping `div`:

```
<div class='privacy_policy'>
    <h2>Some text etc</h2>
    <p>More text ...</p>
    ...
</div>
```

the styling would apply to the enclosed `h2` above, but Firebug tells me that no, the styling has not been applied.

What is the scope of applying a class to a `div`? Does it apply to enclosed elements? Am I having wrong expectations? Am I doing this wrong (if yes, what is the solution)? Am I doing this right and there must be something else happening (if yes where should I look at?)? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wrong selector order ... you want

```
div.privacy_policy h2
```

what you have

```
h2.privacy_policy
```

matches only `h2` elements with class `privacy_policy` explicitly given

p.s. use double quotes for html tag attributes, i.e. `<div class="privacy_policy">` rather than `<div class='privacy_policy'>`

Comment: I did try div.privacy_policy h2, but issue remains. There must be something else.

Comment: No need for double quotes -- double and single quotes are both legal in HTML, and are implemented that way so you can embed quoted values inside an attribute, or embed an entire HTML string inside a string literal without escaping the embedded quote marks. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#Attributes and http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2

Comment: Anyway the question is answered.

Comment: Found my issue: how about I did not refresh my cache properly? Proposed solution works.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS that matches your HTML:

```
h2.privacy_policy {}
```

**or** the HTML that matches your CSS:

```
<h2 class="privacy_policy">Text</h2>
```

Basically, imagine every space is a new level of hierarchy. So, `h2 .privacy_policy` matches a `descendant` of `h2` that has a class of `privacy_policy`, while `h2.privacy_policy` matches `h2` with class of `privacy_policy`.

Answer (score 1):

`h2.privacy_policy` means "only `h2` elements with a class of `privacy_policy`"